# How can I put those two div's on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div's as shown on that picture, [here](http://a3.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/576130_415256775187749_281643650_n.jpg):

How can I make sure than the green is BELOW the red one?

My code is:

```
<div id='black' style='float: left'></div>
<div id='red' style='float: left'></div>
<div id='green' style='float: left'></div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
Group the red and the green divs into a new float:left div
make a new css class called clr.

```
div.clr{clear: both}
```

and try this markup

```
<div id='black' style='float: left'></div>
<div style='float: left'>
  <div id='red' style='float: left'></div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
  <div id='green' style='float: left'></div>
<div>​​​​​​​​​​
```

test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/Hpepy/1/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It solved it for me. Alternatively, I set a maximum width for that parent div you created, without using the `clear:both`. Thanks